# Is there an event that triggers when changing permission for a sheet in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

onEdit and onChanged does not seem to trigger when removing or giving permission to a user.
I have not seen any event related to that in the documentation.
If there is no such events, is there a way to programatically track permission changes?

Edit: I am sorry if the question was not clear but I meant sheet protection permissions for individual sheets inside a workbook instead of Drive sharing permission for the workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to keep track of changes in Sheet protections. As you said, there are no Apps Script triggers that can track this.

#### Workaround (time-based trigger and Properties Service):

As a workaround, I'd propose doing the following:

- Create a time-based trigger that will fire a function periodically ([every 1 minute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyminutesn), for example). You can do this either [manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), or [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically), by running this function once:

```js
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("trackProtections")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1)
  .create();
}
```

This will fire the function `trackProtections` every minute. This function's purpose is to track changes to the sheet protections since last time it was fired (in this example, 1 minute ago).

- In the triggered function, retrieve the current sheet protections, store them in script properties, and compare the previously store protections to the current ones (check [editors](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#getEditors()), etc.). You could use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to be able to store these protections to script properties (which only accept strings) and convert them back. It could be something along the following lines (check inline comments):

```js
function trackProtections() {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // Get script properties (old protections)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); // Get all sheets in spreadsheet
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) { // Iterate through each sheet in the spreadsheet
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();
    // Get sheet current protection (null if it's unprotected):
    var protection = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
    // Get previous editors of current sheet (stored in script properties):
    var oldEditors;
    if (scriptProperties.getProperty(sheetName) !== null) {
      oldEditors = scriptProperties.getProperty(sheetName).split(',');
    }
    // Get current editors of current sheet:
    var newEditors;
    if (protection) {
      newEditors = protection.getEditors().map(function(editor) { 
        return editor.getEmail(); 
      });
    }
    if (oldEditors && !newEditors) { // Protection for the sheet was removed
      scriptProperties.deleteProperty(sheetName); // Remove old property (protection doesn't exist anymore)
      Logger.log('protection for ' + sheetName + ' was removed!');
    } else if (!oldEditors && !newEditors) { // There were and there aren't any protections for the sheet
      Logger.log('there are no protections');
    } else if (!oldEditors && newEditors) { // Protection for the sheet was added
      Logger.log('protection for ' + sheetName + ' was added!');
      scriptProperties.setProperty(sheetName, newEditors.toString()); // Add script property with current editors
    } else {
      if (newEditors.sort().join(',') !== oldEditors.sort().join(',')) { // Check if old and current editors are the same
        var addedEditors = newEditors.filter(function(editor) {
          return oldEditors.indexOf(editor) === -1; // Return editors that are in current protection but not in old one (added)
        });
        var removedEditors = oldEditors.filter(function(editor) {
          return newEditors.indexOf(editor) === -1; // Return editors that were in old protection but not in current one (removed)
        });
        Logger.log('protection for ' + sheetName + ' was modified!');
        Logger.log('these editors were added: ' + JSON.stringify(addedEditors));
        Logger.log('these editors were removed: ' + JSON.stringify(removedEditors));
        scriptProperties.setProperty(sheetName, newEditors.toString()); // Add script property with current editors
      }
    }
  });
}
```

This function iterates through all sheets in the spreadsheet, and looks for changes in the protection since last execution (whether the sheet became protected, or unprotected, or whether the editors changed).

In this sample, the protections are getting stored in script properties the following way: each property has the name of the sheet as the key and the emails of the different editors of the sheet as value (comma-separated). The script is using [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to store the array of editor emails in the property, because script properties only accept strings as value.

You could also keep track of other protection settings that change (description, etc.) which would make the script a bit more complex (and you'd probably have to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, but I hope this simplified example will be enough for you to understand the workflow.

- The function should also check if there is a change between the current protections and the ones that were previously stored, and do whatever you had planned to do when sheet protections changed. Since I don't know what you wanted to do in this situation, I'm just using `Logger.log` to log the changes that happened to the protection since last execution.

#### Reference:

- [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)
- [Class ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#methods)
- [Class PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear, but I meant the protect sheet permissions for the individual sheets in a workbook.

Comment: @Misbah sorry for the confusion. I updated my answer. I provided very general guidelines for a possible workaround. If you think they are too general, but you think this workaround can work for what you want to do, let me know and I'll give more details on how this can be done, maybe with some code snippets.

Comment: @imablichus yes that is more along the lines of what I wanted. I want to keep a log of protection changes and who changed them. If that is not possible, just keep a log of the changes. Some more details and code snippets will be appreciated if you are able to.

Comment: @Misbah I updated my answer with some more details and some code. Please let me know if that works for you.